# How can I add JSON highlighting to the code in Jira comment?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to add a highlighted code to Jira comment? I want to write something like this:

---

The comment text and JSON doc:

```
{
  "key": 100
}
```

---

I've found only one example:

```
{code:javascript}
{
  "key": 100
}
{code}
```

But it does not really highlight my code. I see only the grey block.

Answer (score 53):

With the latest JIRA version you can do the following:

```
{code:json}
{
  "key": 100
}
{code}
```

You can also try to add only `{code}` at the beginning and end of your code block.

```
{code}
{
  "key": 100
}
{code}
```

Comment: This could be helpful as well: https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=advanced

Comment: ^ json highlighting is now supported with `{code:json}` (check CraZ's answer)

Answer (score 37):

Recent Jira 7.5+ starts supporting more languages, including JSON.

Simply use:

```
{code:json}
...
{code}
```

See syntax highlighting in https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftware/jira-software-7-5-x-release-notes-934719297.html#JIRASoftware7.5.xreleasenotes-tweaksMoreimprovements.

See documentation:
https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all

> The default language is Java but you can specify others too, including
>   ActionScript, Ada, AppleScript, bash, C, C#, C++, CSS, Erlang, Go,
>   Groovy, Haskell, HTML, JavaScript, JSON, Lua, Nyan, Objc, Perl, PHP,
>   Python, R, Ruby, Scala, SQL, Swift, VisualBasic, XML and YAML.

Comment: Can confirm that `{code:json}{code}` worked for me using version `Jira 26eaabe8`.

Answer (score 3):

[Default JIRA highlighting syntax list](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=advanced)

If you have the [syntax highlighting plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jira.plugin.syntaxhighlighter.macro.syntaxplugin) you have more, but no JSON as per [its homepage](https://bitbucket.org/hski/syntaxplugin-public/overview) and [this ticket asking for JSON-specific support](https://bitbucket.org/hski/syntaxplugin-public/issues/68/js-json-support#comment-20191701).

Confluence doesn't have JSON-specific highlighting as per [the Confluence formatting docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/code-block-macro-139390.html).

Comment: I think it could be possible to use Javascript highlighting instead of JSON.

Comment: @Finkelson ... Your OP says it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think [jeditor plugin](http://blog.valiantys.com/en/jira-en/how-create-rich-content-jira-issue-fields) will help you to find a solution it will support any type of code blocks you prefer.or you can use rich text editor for your field for more information follow the [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/editing-rich-text-fields-185729567.html) and answer is also in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001222/jira-need-to-add-button-to-comment-toolbar/33005554#33005554)

Comment: I'm kinda looking for a free solution, but JEditor isn't free.

Comment: have you followed this link..https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/editing-rich-text-fields-185729567.html  for this your field need to be support for rich text.