# How to format text such as JSON that contains curly braces in Jira

Tags: json, formatting, jira

I want to put some json within a Jira ticket, but when I highlight json (which is part of the spec), and chose format "Monospaced", it wraps the json in `{{..}}`, but the renderer does **not** render it as monospace - you just see the curly braces and the json rendered in normal font, like this:

{{{"foo" : "bar"}}}

but I want/expect:

```
{"foo" : "bar"}
```

Jira doesn't seem to support formatting json as monospace (who would want to do that, right?!).

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add JSON highlighting to the code in Jira comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635020/how-can-i-add-json-highlighting-to-the-code-in-jira-comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Wrap your json in `{noformat}` tags, like this:

My Jira description...
{noformat}
{"foo" : "bar"}
{noformat}
more description

which gets rendered as:

My Jira description...

```
{"foo" : "bar"}
```

more description